# Why does ng-click not fire in components template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am picking up Angular for a project of mine and am having trouble getting my first steps right.

Specifically, I can get a list of items to display via a component and appropriate template, but I can not figure out how to trigger ng-click events using the component model. Many similar problems to this have been answered on SO but I have followed the many corrections and suggestions without progress and need some advice.

```
file: customerList.js
function CustomerListController($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) {
    this.customerList = [
        { name: 'Arya' },
        { name: 'No One' },
    ];

    this.yell = function(customer) {
        console.log("customer customer, we've got a click");
    };
}

angular.module('myApp').component('customerList', {
    templateUrl: 'customerList.html',
    controller: CustomerListController,
});
```

And its template:

```
file: customerList.html
<div class="customer"
    ng-repeat="customer in $ctrl.customerList"
    customer="customer"
    ng-click="$ctrl.yell(customer);">
        Welcome home, {{customer.name}}!
</div>
```

Even when I set `ng-click="console.log('click detected');"`, I get no console log.

I believe this is sufficient information to diagnose but please let me know if you need more.

Thanks!

Comment: I discovered that I am firing these actions by pushing to the customerList and seeing an update to my page and that my console.log statements are being entirely ignored. This is now my question. I have tried using $log and its various methods and enabling debugging via $logProvider and sending messages down $log.debug. It seems like my angular app has lost a reference to the window?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `console.log` will not work directly in an angular expression. You can't use window functions directly in expressions.

Second, I would recommend using `controllerAs` syntax as it's a newer school way of doing things. Try accessing the controller with your controllerAs alias in the ng-click() expression.

Comment: Thanks for the window functions tip!

I had read that $ctrl was a default for controllerAs. Will test and report back.

Comment: I was not able to trigger the controller's yell method by aliasing. I am making a list on the page, however, so I do have access to the controller.customerList array. Could it be a binding issue?

Comment: Should work so far as I can tell: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kpnknj743Uq6CNSCJwOV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks GBa. You're right - it should have worked. I don't know what the source of the problem I was having was, but it turned out that I was actually logging even though it did not appear in my console. For some reason, anything I entered into my console (even manually) would immediately disappear. A new tab with the same code did not reproduce this bug so I am not sure what happened.